# Django Rest join models on multiple fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models as below.

These models store budget sales data and actual sales data for each project by each month.

```py
# To test join on multiple keys

class ActualSales(models.Model):
    time_id = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    actual_sales = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3)
    adjustment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3)


class BudgetSales(models.Model):
    time_id = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    budget_sales = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3)
```

And the data will somewhat looks like this.

```
Model A

| time_id |  project  | sales | adjustment |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+
| 2019JAN | Project A |  1000 |         10 |
| 2019JAN | Project B |  2500 |          5 |
| 2019FEB | Project A |  1100 |          0 |
| 2019FEB | Project B |  2400 |        -10 |
+---------+-----------+-------+------------+

Model B

| time_id |  project  | budget |
+---------+-----------+--------+
| 2019JAN | Project A |   1100 |
| 2019JAN | Project B |   2400 |
| 2019FEB | Project A |   1000 |
| 2019FEB | Project B |   2500 |
+---------+-----------+--------+
```

And I'm looking to produce an array of objects with each object represent each project's result each month, similarly to the way we join 2 tables with sql. However, I'm unsure how to write the serialiser and API Viewset for this.

```
[
  {
    time_id: "2019JAN",
    project: "Project A",
    sales: "1000",
    adjustment: "10",
    budget: "1100"
  },
  {
    time_id: "2019JAN",
    project: "Project B",
    sales: "2500",
    adjustment: "5",
    budget: "2400"
  },
  {
    time_id: "2019FEB",
    project: "Project A",
    sales: "1100",
    adjustment: "0",
    budget: "1000"
  },
  {
    time_id: "2019FEB",
    project: "Project B",
    sales: "2400",
    adjustment: "-10",
    budget: "2500"
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you have any relationship fields between the models?

Comment: these models don't have relationships between them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

Models.py

```
class ActualSales(models.Model):
    time_id = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    project = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    actual_sales = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3)
    adjustment = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=3)

    def get_budget(self):
        bugdesale = BudgetSales.objects.filter(time_id=self.time_id)
        if bugdesale.exists():
            return bugdesale.first().budget_sales
        else:
            return None
```

Serializers.py

```
class ActualSalesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ActualSales
        fields = ('time_id','project', 'actual_sales', 'adjustment', 'get_budget')
```

Comment: hi Raul, this is fantastic. It's exactly what I was looking for.
Just a little sidetrack, do you know why Django Rest is returning numbers as string for fields in model A, but for the budget_sales in Model B, it's an actual number?

Comment: Hi Kelvin, by default DRF represents DecimaField with a string. If you want to disable it, add in "settings.py" REST_FRAMEWORK = {'COERCE_DECIMAL_TO_STRING': False, ...}. For more details, please visit: 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#decimalfield